# Efficiency of reopening sqlite database after each query

Tags: python, sqlite

I currently am working on a web server in tornado, but am having issues with different bits of code trying to access the database at once.

I have simplified this by simply having a query function which basically does this (but slightly more advanced):

```
def query(command, arguments = []):
    db = sqlite3.open("models/data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(command, arguments)
    result = cursor.findall()
    db.close()
    return result
```

I'm just wondering how efficient it is to reopen the database after every query (I would guess it is a very large constant time operation, or would it cache things or something?), and whether there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Please post actual code, with the right functions, like `connect` and `fetchall` instead of `open` and `findall`.

Comment: What kind of "issues with different bits of code" are you having? If you are trying multiple concurrent writes, use a real RDBMS http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm adding my own answer because I disagree with the currently accepted one. It states that the operation is not thread-safe, but this is plain wrong - [SQLite uses file locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) appropriate to its current platform to ensure that all accesses comply with [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

On Unix systems this will be `fcntl()` or `flock()` locking, which is a per-filehandle lock. As a result, the code posted which makes a new connection each time will always allocate a new filehandle and hence SQLite's own locking will prevent database corruption. A consequence of this is that it's typically a bad idea to use SQLite on an NFS share or similar, as often these don't provide particularly reliable locking (it does depend on your NFS implementation, though).

As @abernert has already pointed out in comments, [SQLite has had issues with threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading), but this was related to sharing a single connection between threads. As he also mentions, this means if you use an application-wide pool you'll get runtime errors if a second thread pulls out a recycled connection from the pool. These are also the sort of irritating bugs which you might not notice in testing (light load, perhaps only a single thread in use), but which could easily cause headaches later. Martijn Pieters' later suggestion of a thread-local pool should work fine.

As outlined in the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) as of version **3.3.1** it's actually safe to pass connections between threads as long as they don't hold any locks - this was a concession that the author of SQLite added despite being critical of the use of threads in general. Any sensible connection pooling implementation will always ensure that everything has been either committed or rolled back prior to replacing the connection in the pool, so actually an application-global pool *would* likely be safe if it wasn't for the Python check against sharing, which I believe remains in place even if a more recent version of SQLite is used. Certainly my Python 2.7.3 system has an `sqlite3` module with `sqlite_version_info` reporting **3.7.9**, yet it still throws a `RuntimeError` if you access it from multiple threads.

In any case, while the check exists then connections can't effectively be shared even if the underlying SQLite library supports it.

As to your original question, certainly creating a new connection each time is less efficient than keeping a pool of connections, but has already been mentioned this would need to be a thread-local pool, which is a slight pain to implement. The overhead of creating a new connection to the database is essentially opening the file and reading the header to make sure it's a valid SQLite file. The overhead of actually executing a statement is higher as it needs to take out looks and perform quite a bit of file I/O, so the bulk of the work is actually deferred until statement execution and/or commit.

Interestingly, however, at least on the Linux systems I've looked at the code to execute statements repeats the steps of reading the file header - as a result, opening a new connection isn't going to be all that bad since the initial read when opening the connection will have pulled the header into the system's filesystem cache. So it boils down to the overhead of opening a single filehandle.

I should also add that if you're expecting your code to scale to high concurrency then SQLite might be a poor choice. As [their own website points out](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) it's not really suitable for high concurrency as the performance hit of having to squeeze all access through a single global lock starts to bite as the number of concurrent threads increases. It's fine if you're using threads for a convenience, but if you're really expecting a high degree of concurrency then I'd avoid SQLite.

In short, I don't think your approach of opening each time is actually all that bad. Could a thread-local pool improve performance? Probably, yes. Would this performance gain be noticeable? In my opinion, not unless you're seeing quite high connection rates, and at that point you'll have a lot of threads so you probably want to move away from SQLite anyway because it doesn't handle concurrency terribly well. If you do decide to use one, make sure it cleans up the connection before returning it to the pool - [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) has some [connection pooling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html) functionality that you might find useful even if you don't want all the ORM layers on top.

**EDIT**

As quite reasonably pointed out I should attach real timings. These are from a fairly low powered VPS:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("cur = conn.cursor(); cur.execute('UPDATE foo SET name=\"x\"
    WHERE id=3'); conn.commit()", setup="import sqlite3;
    conn = sqlite3.connect('./testdb')", number=100000)
5.733098030090332
>>> timeit.timeit("conn = sqlite3.connect('./testdb'); cur = conn.cursor();
    cur.execute('UPDATE foo SET name=\"x\" WHERE id=3'); conn.commit()",
    setup="import sqlite3", number=100000)
16.518677949905396
```

You can see a factor of around 3x difference, which isn't insignificant. However, the absolute time is still sub-millisecond, so unless you do a lot of queries per request then there's probably other places to optimise first. If you do a lot of queries, a reasonable compromise might be a new connection per request (but without the complexity of a pool, just reconnect every time).

For reading (i.e. SELECT) then the relative overhead of connecting each time will be higher, but the absolute overhead in wall clock time should be consistent.

As has already been discussed elsewhere on this question, you should test with real queries, I just wanted to document what I'd done to come to my conclusions.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but… instead of guessing about performance, you can actually test it. And, as you can see from my answer, opening a connection takes about 4-8x as long as a simple query for me, and more than 10x for the OP, which implies that your guess that "opening a new connection isn't going to be all that bad" is wrong. It could easily be the case that the OP's actual queries are so much slower than my simple queries that it turns out not to matter, but you can't assume that a priori.

Comment: I think if you pass `check_same_thread = False` it allows you to share a connection cross thread. My question is if you do that do you still need to provide your own synchronization or will sqllite handle using one connection cross thread for you?

Comment: Recent versions (3.3.1 and later) of SQLite3 allow connections to be used in multiple threads and the `check_same_thread` parameter exists to support this in a way which wouldn't break any legacy code which relied on the old behaviour (or is on a platform where an older version of SQLite is linked in). However, you need to ensure that there aren't any outstanding SQLite file locks - i.e. all statements have been finalised. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) for details. This is an SQLite limitation, not the Python module.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how inefficient something is, write a test and see for yourself.

Once I fixed the bugs to make your example work in the first place, and wrote the code to create a test case to run it against, figuring out how to time it with [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) was as trivial as it usually is.

See http://pastebin.com/rd39vkVa

So, what happens when you run it?

```
$ python2.7 sqlite_test.py 10000
reopen: 2.02089715004
reuse:  0.278793811798
$ python3.3 sqlite_test.py 10000
reopen: 1.8329595914110541
reuse:  0.2124928394332528
$ pypy sqlite_test.py 10000
reopen: 3.87628388405
reuse:  0.760829925537
```

So, opening the database takes about 4 to 8 times as long as running a dead-simple query against a near-empty table that returns nothing. There's your worst case.

Comment: `$ python3.2 test.py 10000`
`reopen: 0.8462200164794922`
`reuse:  0.07594895362854004`
It seems that, given that most of my queries will be a lot bigger than that, it won't make a noticable difference, and given that I'm implementing everything myself, it would be a pain for very little gain. Also, sorry, but I don't know how to put newlines in comments

Comment: @matts: Sadly, as far as I know, you can't put newlines in comments. (You can paste them in, but they get turned into spaces anyway.) Anyway, I'd suggest you try the test with samples of realistic queries for your use case before deciding. If it's 11x for a minimal query, it may still be 2x for a substantial query, which is definitely still noticeable… or it may be 1.001x, in which case you can ignore it. But it's very hard to guess in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reconnect every N sec. In my ajax lookahead/database services whose are 30-40 lines of bottle I reconnect every hour to get the updates,
there are better databases suited if you need to work on live data:

```
t0 = time.time()
con = None
connect_interval_in_sec = 3600

def myconnect(dbfile=<path to dbfile>):
    try:
        mycon = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
        cur = mycon.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')
        data = cur.fetchone()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Error:{}".format(e.args[0]))
        sys.exit(1)
    return mycon
```

And in main loop:

```
if con is None or time.time()-t0 > connect_interval_in_sec:
    con = myconnect()
    t0 = time.time()
<do your query stuff on con>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very inefficient, and not thread-safe to boot.

Use a decent connection pool library instead. [`sqlalchemy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/pooling.html) offers pooling and a whole lot more, or find yourself a lighter-weight pool for sqlite.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not thread-safe?
Doesn't this mean that only one thing is ever accessing the database at the one time?

Comment: @matts: Ah, as it turns out, tornado does not use threads (one assumption striken out). If you were using a multi-threaded application, opening the sqlite database from multiple threads like that would not work.

Comment: Right. So by thread-safe you mean chucks errors like "database is locked"?

Comment: In this particular case, yes, if you are lucky. If there is a race condition in the sqlite locking code, then you could get weirder errors and corruption instead.

Comment: I think you're wrong about thread safety. Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading): "Older SQLite versions had issues with sharing connections between threads. That’s why the Python module disallows sharing connections and cursors between threads. If you still try to do so, you will get an exception at runtime." A connection pool shared across threads doesn't solve a problem; it _creates_ one. (A threadpool with thread-local connections, or a single-threaded connection pool, etc., is a different story.)

Comment: I don't believe it's not thread-safe - AFAIK SQLite uses `flock()` or something similar at the filesystem level. So this approach, while not quite as efficient, is entirely thread-safe, and process-safe as well. File locks are based on the file descriptor and each statement will have its own descriptor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, thread-local pooling means each thread is opening the same database simultaneously, and using the connection only in that thread—which is exactly the same thing the OP's code does. So yes, it is thread-safe, for exactly the same reason the OP's code is.